# Converting .py extension to executable file

Tags: python

Suppose i have a main.py for a calculator application. I used different .py files for different function like(add.py for adding, mul.py for multiplication) and all these files are imported in main.py. When I click main.py it executes successfully and do all function like adding, mul, etc. What i want to do is to make a executable file for main.py so that i can run it in the computer that doesnot have a python installed or any of that module(add.py,..) exist in the hard drive. Is that possible?? 
THANKS FOR THE HELP

Finally I got the solution. PyInstaller works well in my case and it is easy to use too. Thank you for your help. (:

Comment: Got a proverb in italy for that: you want your spouse drunk and the bottle still full. You can't have an os-independent executable, that's why python exists.

Comment: There's no such thing as a single completely machine independent executable. Many systems have mutually incompatible ideas of what an executable is. Would you be willing to relax your restrictions, say, to a number of executables for different systems?

Comment: @EnricoGiampieri That's interesting! The equivalent idiom in English is "You can't have your cake and eat it too."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to have an independent executable that runs on any OS, that's why Python is an interpreted language. What you can do is compile the Python scripts into an executable on each OS you want it to run on, using pyinstaller, so you are have a bunch of different independent programs for different OSs all built on the same Python script.

Pyinstaller has a advantage over py2exe because its easier to compile all the scripts into one file, instead of one directory.

Comment: py2exe also has the ability to "compile" all the scripts into one file. There is an option to create it into a single .exe via setting `{'bundle_files': 1}`

Comment: True, but I find it easier in my opinion using pyinstaller `--onefile`, but it is all a matter of personal choice.

Answer (score 2):

I have no experience of Python, but a simple Google search comes up with py2exe

As for OS independent, that's impossible, that's the whole point of an interpreter. The code is write once run anywhere, but once you compile it, you have to compile it for a specific platform

Answer (score 1):

Short of embedding code and a Python executable (like py2exe does), there's a couple of other possible options (although I've not tried any of them).

- Write it with [Cython](http://cython.org/) and use a compiler to generate executables for all target platforms
- Write it with [Jython](http://www.jython.org/) and generate .class files and run it on the JVM
- Write it with [IronPython](http://ironpython.net/) and have it run on .NET/Mono

Answer (score 0):

Like everyone else has mentioned before, it is not possible to create one executable for multiple OSes. If your question is how I understood it, trying to bundle several .py files that are used in a main .py file, then yes, that is achievable through [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org). You'll need to create a `setup.py` file with the following:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys, os

includes = ['add.py', 'mult.py', 'div.py', 'subt.py']
dll_excludes = ['mswsock.dll', 'powrprof.dll',]

setup(
        console=[{
                'script': 'math.py',
                'name': 'Calculator',
                'version': '1.0',
                'description': 'Basic calculator',
                'author': 'Firstname Lastname'
        }],
        options={
                'py2exe': {
                        'includes': includes,
                        'dll_excludes': dll_excludes,
                        'bundle_files': 1,  # 1 = .exe; 2 = .zip; 3 = separate
                }
        },
        zipfile=None,  # Put libs into .exe to save space.
)
```

Once you save this as `setup.py` then you can create your .exe by running the `setup.py` file.

Comment: but i find pyinstaller much more easy... (: